# How to Programmatically accept Marketplace Terms for ARM template for sendgrid bronze account

Tags: azure, azure-devops, sendgrid, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I was able to create the free sendgrid account using ARM template but not able to create a bronze type account.

```
{
  "name": "[variables('testsendgrid')]",
  "type": "Sendgrid.Email/accounts",
  "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
  "apiVersion": "2015-01-01",
  "plan": {
    "name": "bronze",
    "publisher": "Sendgrid",
    "product": "sendgrid_azure",
    "promotionCode": ""
  },
  "properties": {
    "password": "[variables('pswd')]",
    "acceptMarketingEmails":true,
    "email": "xxx.xx@xx.com"
   }
  }
```

"error": {
   "code": "ResourcePurchaseValidationFailed",
    "message": "User failed validation to purchase resources. Error message: 'Legal terms have not been accepted for this item on this subscription: 'dXXXX-xxxx-xx-xx-xxxxxxxx'. To accept legal terms using PowerShell, please use Get-AzureRmMarketplaceTerms and Set-AzureRmMarketplaceTerms API(https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=862451) or deploy via the Azure portal to accept the terms'"
 }

Answer (score 4):

You need to run a couple of lines of PowerShell to get and set the acceptance of the terms. For example:

```
$terms = Get-AzureRmMarketplaceTerms -Publisher 'SendGrid' -Product 'sendgrid_azure' -Name 'bronze'
Set-AzureRmMarketplaceTerms -Publisher 'SendGrid' -Product 'sendgrid_azure' -Name 'bronze' -Terms $terms -Accept
```

Ensure that the property `Accepted:` is set to `True`. Result:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

From the error you shared issue is because you haven't accepted the the SendGrid terms and condition. You only have to do it once per subscription.

**Powershell:**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.marketplaceordering/Set-AzureRmMarketplaceTerms?view=azurermps-6.13.0

**RestAPI** (since you are using JSON)

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/arsen/2017/10/02/azure-marketplace-api-to-programmatically-review-and-accept-publisher-agreementeula/